# Why compilerArgs can only be set when fork is true?

Tags: java, maven, compilation, maven-compiler-plugin

From the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs):

> Sets the arguments to be passed to the compiler if fork is set to
>   true.

**Why is forking needed in order to use custom arguments?**

Answer (score 4):

> `compilerArgs`:
>
> Sets the arguments to be passed to the compiler if fork is set to true. Example:
>
> ```xml
> <compilerArgs>
>   <arg>-Xmaxerrs=1000</arg>
>   <arg>-Xlint</arg>
>   <arg>-J-Duser.language=en_us</arg>
> </compilerArgs>
> ```

These arguments only make sense when creating a new JVM which is what forking is for.  If you do not fork, the compiler runs in the same JVM as Maven itself.

Comment: Doesn't it have some mechanism to pass on the arguments to the actual module that does the compilation?

Comment: This is for configuring a new JVM - the one running javac - and does not have anything to do with the actual compilation part.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen not really: -Xlint is a javac option, not a JVM option. So is -Xmaxerrs=1000. And the last one could be set as a property before running the compiler in the Maven JVM.

Comment: @JBNizet, right. And I use the `-parameters` javac argument.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, but _this_ particular invocation passes them in through the command line.

Comment: Also note that this is a pretty old thing in Maven, which long predates the compiler API.

Answer (score 1):

Because if fork is not set to true, the compile process happens in the same JVM instance where Maven is running on. And the JVM args would be the same as the JVM args of the instance that Maven is running on. When forking is enabled, compiling happens on a new instance of the JVM and you can set the args of that new instance.